# Why does terminating the default messaging app close the task manager?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

Whenever I close my default messaging app using my "task manager," the "task manager" closes immediately afterwards.  This does not occur when I close any other app.

I currently use Signal, but this also occurred with both the stock Samsung Messaging app and the Android Messaging app.

I'm not sure if this is specific to Samsung devices

Is this a feature?  Can I turn it off?